# Keep referrers for ecommerce tracking in mixed HTTP and HTTPS environment

Tags: google-analytics

I use Google Analytics `ecommerce:addTransaction` to track the revenue after an acquisition.

This works without problems, when my site uses HTTP only.

But since I redirect the client to a SSL page during the buying process I get the payment service provider domains as referrers instead of the real referrers.

This is the Analytics code on the checkout success page:

```
ga('create', 'UA-*******-1', 'example.com');
ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
                        'id': '<?php echo $transaction['id']; ?>',
                        'affiliation': '<?php echo $transaction['affiliation']; ?>',
                        'revenue': '<?php echo $transaction['revenue']; ?>',
                        'shipping': '<?php echo $transaction['shipping']; ?>',
                        'tax': '<?php echo $transaction['revenue']; ?>',
                        'currency': 'EUR'
                    });
// adding items in a loop with ecommerce:addItem
ga('ecommerce:send');
```

The client normally lands on a normal http page. Once redirected to https the client stays on https sites. For example:

1. `http://www.example.com`
2. `https://www.example.com/order`
3. `https://www.example.com/checkout`
4. `https://domain.of.paymentprovider.example.net`
5. `https://www.example.com/success`

Comment: As far as I understand your question the problem is not related to HTTP and HTTPS, which is handled by Analytics correctly, but rather the fact that there is a domain in between which is not 'yours'. In this case you should exclude referrers, see here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en

Comment: But this would require to exclude ALL payment provider domains that can occur. The reason I mention that it does not work in a HTTP/HTTPS environment is simply that it works when I don't redirect the client to the https pendant of my domain. So the tracking itself works, but the referrer is resetted in analytics.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Steps 1, 2 and 3 should not trigger new referrers (but you seem to infer that that's actually the case?). When you get to 4 there's a new domain, this is outside of your scope and will, in step 5, be recorded as a new referral (=new session).

Comment: In step 1 the original referrer could be any external site. When the client is redirected back in 5 from the external domain where I sent him in 4, the original external referrer is overwritten with the domain of the payment service provider.

Comment: Exactly, but why do you think this works "when I don't redirect the client to the https pendant of my domain"? With https pendant of my domain you mean the URLs under 2, 3 and basically 5 right? As far as I understand 4 is the problem. If you exclude all of these payment provider domains you should get the referrer from 1. Sorry if I'm a bit slow in understanding your question

Comment: Yes 2, 3 and 5. I mean that I started using the https redirect since sept. 9th. And that is exactly the date since I get the wrong referrers! Before it was working for at least 1 year.